# XSLT2.0 issue in Concatenation sequence

Tags: xslt

I am trying to do concat of 3 strings:

Input XML:

```
<Data>
    <LExpenseType> Hotel</LExpenseType>
    <VendorName> Beatel Hotel </VendorName>
    <LDescription> Business trip </LDescription>
</Data>
```

My XSLT Logic:

```
<tns:description>
 <xsl:value-of select="LExpenseType[node()]|VendorName[node()]|LDescription[node()]" separator=","/>
 </tns:description>
```

My expectation is : all three values should be returned in sequence with a comma `,` as delimiter; but they are not returned in order.

Please help with this.

Comment: It worked for me, is your input have changes in sequence?

Comment: Well, do you use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor? Are you sure you have `version="2.0"` or `version="3.0"` in place in your stylesheet? Consider to post minimal but complete code samples and problem descriptions to allow others to easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes i used XSLT 2.0, sorry i am in a hurry to fix this issue, so i missed one more point her.

Comment: My Expectation is concatenation should happen in sequence, but it is not happening, i observer it is concatenating in the order of element exist,  for example, if LExpense is a last element, then the result of concatination is VendorName[first element],LDescription[second element],LExpenseType[last element], how to over come this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the union operator `|` then as it orders its nodes in document order, simply use a comma to construct your sequence with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="LExpenseType[node()], VendorName[node()], LDescription[node()]" separator=","/>`.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i will try this in some time, as of now i resolved in some other way by changing the xsd elements.